# pseudo fraction style in inDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting

I need to have text (that represents chapter and verse in a sacred text) typeset like this:

```
49
--
18
```

what I have tried so far is to change the font size to half that of the rest of the text.  Increase the baseline of the 49 and decrease the baseline of the 18.  The -- I leave as is.
(My font doesn't seem to support underlines.) This gives me something like:

```
49
  --
     18
```

But I don't know how to make everything line up.  I've been playing with tracking and kerning but either they are not what I want or more likely I don't know how to use them correctly.

If there is a solution I would like to use it as a style or a macro or something so I don't have to do it by hand each time.  Can anyone help please?

Comment: Can't you just have two separate lines of text, aligned centre, and the dots in the middle on another separate line, then group them all.  Then you could just edit the numbers when needed.  If you need more, then copy and paste the group, and edit the numbers

Comment: Most use slashes for fractions to make the actual numbers easier to read.. a la... ‱ or 1⁄2 ... Many opentype fonts support special fraction glyphs.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using an anchored text frame.

- Create a text frame. Set the height to the same as the leading of the text where you want the fractions to appear. Enter the *Text Frame Options*. Set *General > Vertical Justification > Align* to *Bottom*. Set *Auto-Size > Auto-Sizing* to *Width Only* and tick *Auto-Size > Constraints > No Line Breaks* on.
- (Optionally create a new object style based on the text frame. Call it something like *Fraction Text Frame*.)
- Create a paragraph style called *Fraction Number* for the numerator and denominator. Set its alignment to *Center*. Setting the font size to half the size of the main text is a good starting point.
- Create another paragraph style called *Fraction Line* for the horizontal line. Set its leading to *0*. Add a paragraph rule.
- Enter the text frame and make sure it has three paragraphs. The first one containing a number and styled with *Fraction Number*, the second one empty and styled with *Fraction Line* and the third one also containing a number and styled with *Fraction Number*.

  [image]
- Copy the text frame to clipboard and paste it somewhere in your main text frame.

  [image]
- In the *Fraction Number* paragraph style, tweak the size, leading and weight and in the *Fraction Line* paragraph style, tweak the offset and the weight of the paragraph rule until you have the styling you want.

  [image]
- Now you have dynamic fractions that you can paste wherever you need them.

  [image]

---

In this example I used *Ten Oldstyle Regular*, 12/15 pt. for the main text.

My *Fraction Number* paragraph style settings:

[image]

My *Fraction Line* paragraph style settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could copy a center aligned textfield into the main textfield.

[image]